# How to prove snake lemma in abelian categories without invoking Mitchell's embedding theorem?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

The usual way to prove snake lemma is by diagram chasing, which requires you to work on the elements.

But snake lemma still holds on abelian categories.

Could someone provide a version of proof for snake lemma by chasing arrows?